# Regarding fetching the data

Tags: cakephp

```
    if($filter == 'Key1'){
        $promo = $this->find('all', array('order' => 'Promo.created_on DESC'));

    }else{
        $promo = $this->find('all', array('order' => 'Promo.created_on ASC'));
    }
```

I use this code to filter my database accordingly but if i want to retrieve only 1 row of data from database by using this code:

```
    if($filter == 'Key3'){

        $promo = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Promo.id' => 3)
        ));
    }
```

It will not fetching the result as i want even it cannot working. Please help me out in this

Comment: You should supply some more details. What's the actual problem, what _is_ being fetched, and what do you expect to be fetched instead? Where is this code being executed? What does the generated SQL look like? Is there actually a record with the id `3`? ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If your are writing query in controller you need to specify model name in find query, it seems Promo is model name, so query will be like this

if($filter == 'Key3'){
        $promo = $this->Promo->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Promo.id' => 3),  'order' => array('Promo.created_on asc')));
    }

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Key1 is working but when i click in the key3 it is not workng, actually what i want if i click in key3 , it will fetch the single data which has id 3